# SwiftUI UITextView Coordinator not working

Tags: swiftui

I have wrapped a `UITextView` in a `UIViewRepresentable` and included a `Coordinator` as `UITextViewDelegate`, but the events are not called. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct TextView : UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView

    var placeholder : String

    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextView>) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        let placeholderLabel = UILabel()        
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 16)
        placeholderLabel.restorationIdentifier = "Placeholder"
        placeholderLabel.text = self.placeholder
        placeholderLabel.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: (textView.font?.pointSize)!)
        placeholderLabel.sizeToFit()
        textView.addSubview(placeholderLabel)
        placeholderLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 25, y: (textView.font?.pointSize)! / 2 + 12)
        placeholderLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        placeholderLabel.isHidden = !textView.text.isEmpty

        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextView>) {
        uiView.text = self.text
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

        var parent: TextView

        init(_ uiTextView: TextView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            print("Not working")
            return true
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            print("Not working")
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Little off topic, but the placehiolderlabel does not disappear when I start typing into the uitextview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `textView.delegate = context.coordinator` to `makeUIView` to register the coordinator to receive updates from `UITextView`.

Comment: Thanks that's what I missed ... How obvious -.-

Comment: I had the same gotcha the first time :-)

Comment: In my opinion this is fail by design because the Coordinator and the UIViewRepresentable knows both types and the function makeUIView returns the actual object so why not attach it by design?

Comment: I hope I don't misunderstand! Attach to a delegate attribute `UIViewRepresentable` knows nothing about the `Coordinator` `UIViewRepresentable` of which it does not know whether the user wants it? :-). Well it's probably possible to figure out with lot's of reflection but probably costs too much and too magic.

Comment: You might be right but doesn't makeCoordinator return the Coordinator? So why not wrap this behind the scenes? :) Yeah too much magic is not good :P

Comment: Little off topic, but the `placehiolderlabel` does not disappear when I start typing into the uitextview?

Comment: @Learn2Code I can only guess here. makeUIView is the only one setting ˋisHiddenˋ. If you want it to hide when the text gets empty you probably have to do it when SwiftUI handles binding variable changes, inside updateUIView. You probably have to get the label from the text views' subviews to get it working. This should be a new question :) You can maybe use a coordinator to hold the text view besides the label and access them in updateUIView, see for an example the other answer or the question.

Answer (score 13):

This is a working example in Xcode Version 11.0 beta 6:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
     @State var text = ""

       var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("text is: \(text)")
            TextView(
                text: $text
            )
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }

       }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {

        let myTextView = UITextView()
        myTextView.delegate = context.coordinator

        myTextView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
        myTextView.isEditable = true
        myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.05)

        return myTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

        var parent: TextView

        init(_ uiTextView: TextView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            print("text now: \(String(describing: textView.text!))")
            self.parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just completed my own wrapper of UITextView but I didn't include the textView method in Coordinator. The default behaviour seems to be to allow the change so I wondered why you included it.

Comment: Thanks for this. It also works without change on Mac OS.