# How to create a multiline TextField in SwiftUi ? like the notes app?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to create a multiline textfield that automatically ads line breaks and with scroll view, just like the notes app, is there any direct way we can do this in SwiftUI ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Notes App uses a Table View, though we can't be entirely sure since the Notes App is closed source. You could have a table view with custom cells that are entirely text fields and change the height of the cell based on what font size the user selected. Other than that AFAIK this is the best existing way as of today to do this.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530722/swiftui-wrapper-for-uitextview-not-updating-observedobject

Answer (score 10):

This works in Xcode Version 11.0 beta 6:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
     @State var text = ""

       var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("text is: \(text)")
            TextView(
                text: $text
            )
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }

       }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {

        let myTextView = UITextView()
        myTextView.delegate = context.coordinator

        myTextView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
        myTextView.isEditable = true
        myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.05)

        return myTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {

        var parent: TextView

        init(_ uiTextView: TextView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            print("text now: \(String(describing: textView.text!))")
            self.parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
TextEditor(text: $text)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is essentially a `UITextView`. There is no current equivalent in SwiftUI, so you'll have to use a `UIViewRepresentable` struct to achieve this. See [Apple's SwiftUI + UIKit tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) for how to wrap UIKit views and view controllers for use in SwiftUI and see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597060/swiftui-uitextview-coordinator-not-working) for a possible implementation (and solution to an easy to overlook detail.)