# SwiftUI Wrapper for UITextView not updating ObservedObject

Tags: xcode, swiftui, combine

I hope I'm wrong, but I have not been able to find a SwiftUI equivalent to an editable
UITextView. So, I built one using UIViewRepresentable. Populating both a SwiftUI Text
and my own view with the ObservableObject works - but updates made in my view are
not propagated to the ObservableObject. I must be missing something important with
the Binding concept. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var myOText: MyOText

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("This is a bound Text View")
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text(myOText.inTheCourse)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .padding()

                Text("This is a multi-line UITextView wrapper:")
                    .font(.headline)

                MultilineTextView(myOText: myOText)
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .padding()

                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MultilineTextView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var myOText: MyOText

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 20)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = myOText.inTheCourse
    }
}

class MyOText: ObservableObject {
    @Published var inTheCourse: String = "When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them ..."
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(myOText: MyOText())
    }
}
```

[image] 
Xcode Version 11.2 beta 2 (11B44), iOS 13.

Comment: Do changes to `inTheCourse` propagate to your UIKit view? I ask because in my case changes in my `@ObservedObject` don't trigger `updateUIViewController` (using `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in my case).

Comment: I am not using it that way. I save the myOText to Core Data, then of course load from Core Data. However, I did a simplified test with a myOText, a TextField and a Text View all connected to the ObservedObject, and typing in the TextField updated the Text View but did not update the myOText - just as you suggest. Must be someway to instruct the coordinator to do that. Maybe Jeff or someone can comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your multiline text view needs a coordinator to observe the text updates from  UITextView

```
struct MultilineTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var myOText: MyOText

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.textAlignment = .center
        view.font = UIFont(name: "Times New Roman", size: 20)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = myOText.inTheCourse
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MultilineTextView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var control: MultilineTextView

        init(_ control: MultilineTextView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            control.myOText.inTheCourse = textView.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a champ.

Comment: It's weird but UITextView wrapped this way reacts to return by jumping the cursor to the end of the whole text. Similarly it jumps to the end of the text when pressing backspace on the empty line.

Comment: @jeff how could I make a default text (greyed outish) show up in, and once the user enters his text then the regular black text replaces it, and vice versa if they remove the text?

Comment: @Munhitsu I had the same cursor jumping issue and fixed it in my updateUIView by only updating the UITextView’s text if it has changed.