# How to display long texts/articles in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, text, blogs, swiftui

I'm trying to make a blog type app. I don't know yet how to properly display good-looking texts in SwiftUi. The article is couple of pages on DIN4 paper and has a lot of paragraphs. I'm relatively new to SwiftUi or coding in general so this is how each of my paragraphs look like:

```
Text("Random Text to fill in about a paragraph to show how my code looks. I don't know if anyone will read this but I'm writing it anyway.")
       .font(.body)
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
       .padding(.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
       //or .padding(.init(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
```

The problem I'm running into is I'm overloading the app. There's too many text modules which take too long or don't load at all. 
    How do I display a nice looking article easily and make it easy for me to write more fast?

Comment: Would recommend UITextView with ViewRepresentable. See reference here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57679966/how-to-create-a-multiline-textfield-in-swiftui-like-the-notes-app

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use Markdown files for each article.

In iOS 15 Apple added native markdown support to SwiftUI Text Views.

Unfortunately, it only supports a subset of Markdown features which are: bold, italics, links, strikethrough, and monospace.

Does not support headings, ordered or unordered lists, or images.

You can display markdown directly in a Text() like this:

```
Text("Markdown **bold**")
Text("This is *italic*")
Text("Strike through text like this ~~striken through~~")
Text("`monospaced text`")
Text("Link: [Link text](www.iiroalhonen.com)")
```

Or you can display it from a file like this:

```
struct markdownFileView: View {
    // Get the path to your markdown file.
    let filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "markdownFileName", withExtension: "md")
    
    var body: some View {
        // Show the markdown here
        Text(try! AttributedString(
                      contentsOf: filepath!,
                      options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(
                            interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace
                        )))
    }
}
```

The `options: AttributedString.MarkdownParsingOptions(interpretedSyntax: .inlineOnlyPreservingWhitespace` is important if you want the line breaks, without it runs into one big text blob.

**One important note:** If you are adding your articles as markdown files directly in Xcode, sometimes dragging your markdown file to the Assets doesn't add it to your app bundle.

This means when you run the app, it won't find a file, so `filepath` will be nil so force unwrapping it with the `!` will result in a crash.

So make sure your file was included in the Build Phase > Copy Bundle Resources, by [following the instructions in this SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129166/1296746)

By doing this you can display long articles written in simple markdown in your SwiftUI app.

I found this article very helpful - https://iiroalhonen.medium.com/displaying-markdown-using-swiftui-e16131a9dc52

And I found the solution to new lines not being rendered here - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682957