# SwiftUI display characters count remaining in a label/text

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have UITextView which I would like to display the current character count to the user?

I can easily do this in swift and storyboards, but I an unsure how to do so in SwiftUI?

How do I get the "reference" to the label/text which would hold and display the character count to the users?

Here is the code for my view:

```
    Section(header: Text("Additional Information")) {

        MultilineTextView(text: $notes)


        Text("\(String(notes.count))") 

    }
```

This always displays zero (0)

Comment: It is hard to imagine what you do inside `MultilineTextView` with binding. Would you show code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed something similar so I got this extension for the Binding class

```
extension Binding {
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                let snapshot = self.wrappedValue                    
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute(snapshot)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This will allow to listen to changes on bindings

Now comes the easy part, getting the count and showing it

```
@State var charCount: Int
// code until this section
Section(header: Text("Additional Information")) {

   MultilineTextView(text: $notes.didSet(execute: { (value: String) in self.countLeft(value) }))
   Text("\(String(charCount))") 

}
// outside the body
func getCount(_ value: String) {
    self.charCount = value.count
}
```

You can improve your UI using `ZStack`, `VStack`, `HStack` and `Spacer()` I can not figure out how do you want to display it so I just took your example.

Also, if it's a simple function, for example a count, you don't need to declare a function you can write it in the closure like so

```swift
// ...
MultilineTextView(text: $notes.didSet(execute: { (value: String) in self.charCount = value.count }))
```