# How to trigger a function via variable change (binding)

Tags: swiftui

I have a timer view which I want to reuse and I want to start the timer by my binding variable running like this:

Unfortunately I am (too?) tired this morning to find a solution how to do that. :(

Maybe my solution is bad and there is a much easier way!?

```
struct TimerView: View {

    @State var hours : Int = 0
    @State var minutes : Int = 0
    @State var seconds : Int = 0
    @State var hundred : Int = 0

    @Binding var running : Bool

    let timer = Timer.publish (every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common)
    @State var cancellable : Cancellable?

    func start() {
        self.cancellable = timer.connect()
    }

    func stop() {
        cancellable!.cancel()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following, create this extension

```swift
extension Binding {
    func didSet(execute: @escaping (Value) ->Void) -> Binding {
        return Binding(
            get: {
                return self.wrappedValue
            },
            set: {
                let snapshot = self.wrappedValue
                self.wrappedValue = $0
                execute(snapshot)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And the the parent view, not `TimerView` you can have something like this

```swift
//[...]
TimerView(running: $running.didSet{ value in /* your code or function here*/ })
//[...]
```

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61535571/1152683)

#### UPDATE 1

Based on the comment what I understood is that the you want to start/stop the timer from outside the TimerView.

I found a couple ways to do that

First one declare the TimerView as a variable in the parent view

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var running: Bool = false
    @State var timerView: TimerView? = nil
    init() {
        timerView = TimerView(running: $running)
    }
    // rest...
}
```

But depending on your init it can be a pain so I created a small extension that allows you to reference the view like so

```swift
extension View {
    func `referenced`<T>(by reference: Binding<T>) -> (Self?){
        DispatchQueue.main.async { reference.wrappedValue = self as! T }
        return self
    }
}
```

The usage of this extension is rather simple

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var running: Bool = false
    @State var timerView: TimerView? = nil
    var body: some View {
        TimerView(running: $running).referenced(by: $timerView)
    }
}
```

Then you can control it using for instance a button `Button(action: self.timerView.start()) { Text("Start Timer") }`

If tested this code against your TimerView but seems there's something wrong in the `stop()` code. I commented the line `cancellable!.cancel()` and added a `print` instead and everything is working as expected.

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/3a0FQL8v) the test code that I used in Xcode Playground

I hope this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I am deleting the comment not to make people confuse :)

Comment: hi pedro, thank you for your answer, but i want to do something (run function starttimer) in the  timerview, when running was changed from the outside to yes....